# Xml attribute rendering oddness

Tags: scala

Using 2.9.0.1

`<b time={None}>Hello</b>`

=>

`<b >Hello</b>`

i.e. there is a space after the b in the starting tag. 
This makes no sense from an XML perspective.

Is this "feature" supposed to happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Have seen those spaces too. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because of toString implementation of scala.xml.Elem, to be more specific
in object scala.xml.MetaInf method buildString which looks like following:

```
 def buildString(sb: StringBuilder): StringBuilder = {
  sb.append(' ')
  toString1(sb)
  next.buildString(sb)
 }
```

So it's firstly adds a white space to string representation of element, and only after that appends next attribute, so if an attribute is  present as class member but doesn't have any string representation you'll end up with one extra space before closing bracket

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is allowed. See [Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition), 3.1 Start-Tags, End-Tags, and Empty-Element Tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags). From there:

```
STag ::= '<' Name (S Attribute)* S? '>'
```

Where S is whitespace and Attribute is an attribute definition. The same is true for end elements:

```
ETag ::= '</' Name S? '>'
```

So this is allowed. Whether or not it's what you want is another thing :-)

Comment: Oh yes, I know it is allowed from an XML perspective (I do XSLT/XQuery etc), just wondering as to why this would happen, i.e. is it some deliberate cleverness beyond my grasp or just a bug?

Comment: No, I don't think its cleverness, nor could it be described as a bug either. The XMl with and without the whitespace are equivalent, so it (theoretically) doesn't matter if the space is there or not. The space is just left over because the time attribute is removed. Try <b time={None} date={None}>Hello</b>. This results in <b  >Hello</b> (with two spaces).

Comment: Undesirable I'd say, I'd prefer my xml not to be emitted with extraneous whitespace. Given the spec it would be ok to have random amounts of whitespace added, but I wouldn't like that either.